# Top panel icons disappear after sleep/suspend (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: suspend, icons, gnome-shell, panel

I have been having this problem since prior to the Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade, so I don't think it's release-dependent.

When my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 720) comes back from sleep mode, many of the dock icons on the top panel are missing. The applications have not stopped running, but the icons don't come back.

The workaround I've found is to log out and log back in.

Here is a picture of the top panel before sleep:

Top panel before sleep
[image: Top panel before sleep]

Here is the top panel after sleep:

Top panel after sleep
[image: Top panel after sleep]

Comment: Ok.. press Alt+F2 and then type `restart` and hit enter instead of relogin as a workaround.

Comment: This works! Is there a way to do this automatically or find out why it's happening?

Comment: Gnome shell extensions are disabled when system goes to sleep.. When system wakes up the extensions are enabled. During this process "ubuntu app indicator" shell extension is not working properly.. When you restart the shell it starts working.

Comment: i have a similar of not the same problem. however i run the default ubuntu gnome gnome desktop. if i wake up PC from suspend/sleep it sometimes happen, that the whole thing freezes and is unresponsive (everything but mouse!) . even SHIFT+ALT+Fx wont work then for whatever reason. If i then brute force down the system with hardware reset it often loses my favourites symbols on the dock to the left. to me this seems to be something new, since this never  happened some weeks ago, but these days it happens every week or so.